# Image-Resize-Crop-imageResizer is not working from top jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, image-resizing

I am using resize image that crop the image I see demo it does not work from top cropping, had anybody chance to fix it

```
https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Image-Resize-Crop-imageResizer/
```

Comment: What's the issue? I cannot break it myself.

Comment: Is this demo working fine ? try to crop it from top to bottom It does not work